# mona is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported

Tags: 14.04, permissions, sudo, root

So I just did a `sudo apt-get upgrade` and said `Y` to a question it asked me and now I am not a sudoer anymore. Even our root isn't a sudoer anymore. What's the solution?

```
Configuration file '/etc/sudoers'
 ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
 ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** sudoers (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ? Y
Installing new version of config file /etc/sudoers ...
Setting up apt-transport-https (1.0.1ubuntu2.15) ...
Setting up libisc95 (1:9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.10) ...
Setting up libdns100 (1:9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.10) ...
Setting up libisccc90 (1:9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.10) ...
Setting up libisccfg90 (1:9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.10) ...
Setting up libbind9-90 (1:9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.10) ...
Setting up liblwres90 (1:9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.10) ...
Setting up bind9-host (1:9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.10) ...
Setting up dnsutils (1:9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.10) ...
Setting up dbus (1.6.18-0ubuntu4.4) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/dbus-1/system.conf ...
Setting up python3-update-manager (1:0.196.22) ...
Setting up update-manager-core (1:0.196.22) ...
Setting up bazel (0.4.0) ...
Setting up cuda-repo-ubuntu1404 (8.0.44-1) ...
OK
Setting up dbus-x11 (1.6.18-0ubuntu4.4) ...
Setting up dkms (2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04.9) ...
Setting up firefox (49.0.2+build2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Please restart all running instances of firefox, or you will experience problems.
Setting up libxnvctrl0 (361.93.02-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up linux-generic-lts-saucy (3.13.0.100.108) ...
Setting up linux-headers-generic-lts-saucy (3.13.0.100.108) ...
Setting up linux-image-generic-lts-saucy (3.13.0.100.108) ...
Setting up linux-libc-dev:amd64 (3.13.0-100.147) ...
Setting up linux-tools-common (3.13.0-100.147) ...
Setting up python-pil (2.3.0-1ubuntu3.3) ...
Setting up python-imaging (2.3.0-1ubuntu3.3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.9) ...
mona@pascal:~/computer_vision/deep_learning/ssd/caffe$ sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake git pkg-config
mona is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.


mona@pascal:~$ pwd
/home/mona
mona@pascal:~$ su -
Password: 
su: Authentication failure


mona@pascal:~$ sudo passwd root
[sudo] password for mona: 
mona is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

UPDATE: In the grub, I selected advanced options and then recovery mode -> root and changed the password using passwd mona and set the passwd however it still doesn't let me sudo after rebooting! Please suggest solutions.

```
mona@pascal:~$ su -
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
```

Comment: Wow a perfect shot into the maintainers' leg. File a bug with ubuntu when you get finished fixing this.

Comment: [Related xkcd comic.](https://xkcd.com/838/)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen The comic doesn't show his face so... who gets the report and what does it look like?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The usual way to give `sudo` rights to an account in Ubuntu is to add it to the `admin` and/or `sudo` groups, which are given `sudo` rights by default.

If you really want to modify your sudoers configuration, you should not edit `/etc/sudoers` directly, but add your local configuration in a separate file in the directory `/etc/sudoers.d` as described in `man sudoers`. This is to avoid the problem you just experienced: since your changes will not be in `/etc/sudoers`, you can safely upgrade it to newer versions without losing your configuration.

In order to modify system files if `sudo` won't work, you can go through [recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode). You can then, for example, add `mona` to the `sudo` group with

```
usermod -aG sudo mona
```

Comment: This is a better answer than mine, and the one you should follow.

Comment: Please see updated question. Setting a new password for root didn't work!

Comment: Nobody said that setting a new password would solve your problem...

Comment: we needed what I suggested in edit   mount -rw -o remount / before usermod -aG sudo mona

Comment: It is already included in the page linked.

Comment: @fkraiem: but a new *root* password would and that's how I interpreted that note. On having a now root password there's now 10,000 ways of fixing this.

Answer (score 4):

Whoops, your "Y" accepted a new version of the sudoers file that obviously doesn't have you in it! In the future, a "D" to compare them would have been a better option, though it's also not clear that this should have happened in the first place: having your sudoers file replaced while installing software is not very professional. At this point, you'll need to log in as root (not yourself with sudo) and re-add yourself ("mona") to the Users section of the file.

Comment: Worth noting that the usual way to give a user `sudo` access is by adding their account to the `sudo` group - rather than adding specific users or additional groups to the `sudoers` file

Comment: That's true, yeah. Apparently Mona had her system configured differently, though your point still stands and it might be a better idea to do that.

Comment: @steeldriver: That's ubuntu-specific. The usual way for sudo is to edit the sudoers file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a command like this:

```
sudo gpasswd -a username sudo
```

In place of *`username`*, put the username you want added to the `sudo` group. If you run `sudo gpasswd -a mono sudo`, it gives `sudo` privileges to the `mono` user and, due to the `-a` option, actually adds that user to the `sudo` group.