# How To Restart Sudo Service on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: sudo, 16.10

I just migrated over to Ubuntu 16.10 from Debian Testing and modified the sudoers file, but there doesn't appear to be a 'sudo' service that I can restart to get it to recognize the changes.

Does this involve some SystemD magic?

Comment: I don't think you need to do anything besides modify the file.

Comment: Changes should take effect right away, sudo is a command not a service.

Comment: You should [avoid modifying `/etc/sudoers`](http://askubuntu.com/questions/846738/mona-is-not-in-the-sudoers-file-this-incident-will-be-reported/846748#846748).

Answer (score 7):

There is no service working beyond `sudo`. When someone executes `sudo` it checks the sudoers policy. And sudoers policy checks the `/etc/sudoers` file or LDAP.

So you don’t need to restart any service.