# Configure sudo to keep SSH_AUTH_SOCK

Tags: ssh, sudo, environment-variables

What's the proper way to configure `sudo` to keep the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable?

I was following some guide on the Internet, but it is not working for me:

```
$ printenv | grep SSH
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-Zy2v8uDtJxPw/agent.2628
SSH_AGENT_PID=2629

$ sudo printenv | grep SSH | wc 
      0       0       0
```

I thought I need to restart `sudo` service, but 
[How To Restart Sudo Service on Ubuntu 16.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/850201/) says no need.

Comment: Check out the `env_keep` option in `/etc/sudoers` (`man sudoers`).

Comment: I know the env_keep option and I've added SSH_AUTH_SOCK, but it is not working, without restarting Sudo Service, as seen in OP. Your comment doesn't provide much help I'm afraid, @GunnarHjalmarsson. Have you actually tried it before your reply?

Comment: It was sad that pointing at the documented way to do it wasn't helpful. Good luck!

Comment: That's a very weird  way to show being helpful. Guess how many git questions are asked on stackoverflow, despite there are _"documented way to do it"_, then check out if your guess was close enough at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo -E printenv | grep SSH
```

`-E` Preserves your environment variables into the sudo.

Comment: Kudo! Thanks a lot Jeffrey with my +25!